# Can I use geofence and monitoring track without Internet connection?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I want to track the movement of user between two geofences areas. I want to store in memory (SharedPrefs) the time that user made between the two areas.

Can I do this without use the internet ? Only with GPS ?

Comment: Are the above answers correct? why you haven't mark any as the answer?

Comment: yes, both of them are correct

Comment: I think it's more clear to accept at least one

Comment: that happend a year ago! you're strange

Comment: I have questions 4 years old, and still get new answers for :)

Comment: I am sorry man, I will accept one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should work without network connection using GPS & Triangulation. I will recommend you turn WiFi on also because even do it doesn't need to be connected, if WiFi is on it can estimate also the location based on the WiFi's near by.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create and monitor geofences without internet connection. You can track changes in current location using GPS. For each geofence, [LocationServices](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices) class is responsible for sending you entering and exit events.You can listen for geofence transition using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or BroadcastReceiver.

You are also required to set ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your manifest file